# How to use calculated fields for math in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a mongo aggregate query that creates a few calculated fields using $project:. I have found that the calculated fields aren't usable for further calculations by mongo shell, as it starts complaining that it can't convert strings to numbers.

Is there a workaround for this? The query works without using calculated fields, but it requires that I re-calculate everything for each math operation I want to do, slowing the query down immensely.

**Update:**

The following query returns this error:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: $mod only supports numeric types, not String and NumberDouble",
"code" : 16611,
"ok" : 0
```

Granted, the query example is non-sensical in its use case, but the expectation for it to perform the math is the same:

```
db.books.aggregate([
{$project:  {
    'priceToInflationRatio': {$multiply: [{'$divide': [{'$subtract': ['$price', 1]}, 5]}, 10]},                                                    
    'priceInflationresult':
        {'$cond': [
                {'$gt': ['$price', 5]},
                    {'$mod': [
                        'priceToInflationRatio',
                        1]},
                1
        ]},
}}
])
```

If I use:

```
                    {'$mod': [
                        '$priceToInflationRatio',
                        1]},
```

The calculation result is always null.

**Update 2 - Possible Solution:**

I may have stumbled on the solution: use 2 different $project sections. It seems if I reference a field created in the same $project section, it doesn't know about it yet. Ergo, I need to make all calculated fields in one section, then reference them in another.

The following appears to work:

```
db.books.aggregate([
{$project:  {
    'priceToInflationRatio': {$multiply: [{'$divide': [{'$subtract': ['$price', 1]}, 5]}, 10]}
}},
{$project: {
    'priceInflationresult':
        {'$cond': [
                {'$gt': ['$price', 5]},
                    {'$mod': [
                        '$priceToInflationRatio',
                        1]},
                1
        ]},
}}
])
```

Is this assumption correct, and would this be the correct way to do it? (I'm having a difficult time coming from SQL to learn how to construct queries in Mongo, so please bear with me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works, but you can clean it up a bit by using [`$let`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/#exp._S_let) to define `priceToInflationRatio` as a variable within the `$project` so you can use just one stage:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  {$project: {
    'priceInflationresult': {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          'priceToInflationRatio': {
            $multiply: [{'$divide': [{'$subtract': ['$price', 1]}, 5]}, 10]
          }
        },
        in: {
          '$cond': [
            {'$gt': ['$price', 5]},
            {'$mod': ['$$priceToInflationRatio', 1]},
            1
          ]
        },
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this more clearly. I will study up on $let and use it. :)

Comment: @mike.bronner Yep, the `$$` prefix is needed to access `$let` variables.

Comment: is it possible to use $let variables across let blocks, or somehow declare variables that can be used across the entire scope of the $project section?

Comment: This becomes important when I want to use $$priceToInflationRatio to calculate multiple other fields.

Comment: @mike.bronner Understood. That's probably best asked as a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047302/mongodb-aggregate-variable-to-create-multiple-fields