# MongoDB Aggregate Variable to create Multiple Fields?

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

Given the following query, what is the best method to use $$priceToInflationRatio to help create multiple calculated fields? From what I have read on $let, it appears to only work for creating a single field -- I would like to use the variables across my entire $project section. Is that possible?

```
db.books.aggregate([
  {$project: {
        'priceInflationresult': {
            $let: {
                vars: {
                    'priceToInflationRatio': {
                        $multiply: [{'$divide': [{'$subtract': ['$price', 1]}, 5]}, 10]
          }
        },
        in: {
            '$cond': [
            {'$gt': ['$price', 5]},
            {'$mod': ['$$priceToInflationRatio', 1]},
            1
          ]
        },
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `in` part of a `$let` expression is an object, so it can accept multiple keys, each of which can be an expression that is evaluated with the variables in scope:

```
> db.test.insert({ "_id" : 0, "a" : 1, "b" : 1 })
> db.test.aggregate([{
    "$project" : {
        "test" : {
            "$let" : {
                "vars" : {
                    "c" : 2,
                    "d" : 3
                },
                "in": {
                    "a" : { "$add" : ["$a", "$$c"] },
                    "b" : { "$add" : ["$b", "$$d"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
{ "_id" : 0, "test" : { "a" : 3, "b" : 4 } }
```

Note that this will necessarily create subdocuments as top-level $let expressions are not allowed. You can change this with another $project stage.

Comment: Thank you for your example. I have used multiple $project stages to get around it for now. Was hoping to have top-level $let, or something similar. Also interesting to consider the sub-document solution, I didn't think of that. That way I could reference the newly-created sub-document in a subsequent $let. Are multiple $lets or $project roughly equivalent in performance, or is there an advantage to one over the other?

Comment: I couldn't say performance-wise. Both should be fast. The best guide will have to be your own tests but I'm guessing the difference is small enough that using whichever way is easier for you to maintain may be best.